# What do two double quotes really mean for a string variable in C#?

Tags: c#, string, null

I've recently encountered an problem that has me wondering what two double quotes means to the compiler in C#.

```
string Var, blankVar;

Var = null; //Var is not instantiated or defined.
Var = ""; //Var should be blank or empty, but it is not null.
Var = "house"; //Var is defined as the string value house.
blankVar = ""; //blankVar should be blank or empty, but it is not null.
```

At this point the compiler should have the value of "house" stored into the string variable Var. The string variable blankVar should be empty.

```
if (Var.Contains(blankVar)) //if "house" contains "" then..
{
// do something
}
```

If Var is equal to "house" and does not contain empty (""), why is the compiler still stepping into the if statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every string contains the empty string. Logically, this makes sense, as every string contains some substring of zero length, including the empty string itself.

The `Contains` method simply reflects this. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>   Type: `System.Boolean`
>   **true** if the *value* parameter occurs within this string, or if *value* is the empty string (""); otherwise, **false**.

Comment: One can even argue the documentation is stating the obvious (except, of course, for the OP....).

Comment: @Jongware Yeah, it may not be obvious to everybody. I remember when I first learned about the empty set, and that it is a subset of every other set, including itself. It surprised me at the time (though after thinking about it for a bit I realized that it *had* to be that way).